# Will a non-US citizen living and working in the US be eligible for stimulus check?

Tags: united-states, irs, stimulus, immigration, covid-19

Please excuse me if this question doesn't fit very well here in this forum, but I don't know which SE would be more suitable for my question than Money.SE, so I decided to ask it here.

My question basically needs a mixture of immigration and financial pieces of knowledge.

I'm a Ph.D. student that I live and work in the US from September 2016, but my visa status is the student visa. I have on-campus employment income as 20K per year and from 2016, I filed my tax return correctly each year including my 2019 tax return. Also, my 2019 tax return was processed a couple of weeks ago and I received my refund successfully. Furthermore, I have SSN (Social Security Number). Will I be eligible for a stimulus check or not? By the way, still, I'm receiving my salary despite the fact that I don't work on-campus because of this crisis and I just work online from my home.

Comment: Do you have an SSN? If no, the answer is "NO, you don't get one"

Comment: @Aganju I have SSN.

Comment: Then you suould get a check - if your income wasn't too high. Congrats!

Comment: @Aganju Thanks! My income is 20K per year.

Comment: Had you ever been in the US in F or J status prior to 2016?

Comment: @user102008 No, I entered the US for the first time on September 2016.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The texts I have seen ([Senate bill](https://www.congress.gov/bill/116th-congress/senate-bill/3548/text) and [House bill](https://www.congress.gov/bill/116th-congress/house-bill/748/text)) carve out some exceptions in the definitions section (emphasis mine):

> (3) ELIGIBLE INDIVIDUAL.—**The term ‘eligible individual’ means any individual other than**—
>
> “(A) **any nonresident alien individual,**
>
> “(B) any individual with respect to whom a deduction under section 151 is allowable to another taxpayer for a taxable year beginning in the calendar year in which the individual’s taxable year begins, and
>
> “(C) an estate or trust.

[So, nonresident aliens (for tax purposes](https://www.law360.com/tax-authority/articles/1257333/immigrants-cut-out-of-senate-s-covid-19-stimulus-package)) will not get stimulus checks. Since you're on a student visa (presumably F-1) only since 2016, you most likely filed your 2019 taxes as a nonresident alien (Form 1040NR), and thus most likely won't get a check. Sorry.

---

To be considered a resident alien, one needs to pass the [substantial presence test](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/the-green-card-test-and-the-substantial-presence-test). A person on a student visa must, in addition, be in the country five years (not necessarily consecutive) before being able to apply the test. Going by IRS' [example](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/alien-residency-examples), a student who arrived in 2015 would become resident (for tax purposes) in 2020. A person who arrived in 2016, would not until 2021, which should also make it impossible to claim the money as a tax credit on the 2020 taxes.